# Best practice to send a lot of files (images) from your device to your server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, threadpool

I have a list of files to send from my device to my server.

```
List<myFiles> list = new List<myFiles>() { "[long list of files...]" };
```

For that I want to create a list of tasks: for each file I should invoke a function that sends to my webapi that file via `PUT`

```
public async Task<bool> UploadPhoto(byte[] photoBytes, int PropertyId, string fileName)
{
    bool rtn = false;

    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
    {
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(photoBytes);
        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = 
                            MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
                            new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = fileName + ".jpg"
        };
        content.Add(fileContent);

        string url = RestURL() + "InventoriesPicture/Put";

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authenticationToken", SyncData.Token);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(url, content);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    rtn = true;
                    Debug.WriteLine($"UploadPhoto response {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"UploadPhoto response {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"UploadPhoto exception {ex.Message}");
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"UploadPhoto ends {fileName}");
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

In a function I have a `foreach` that calls `UploadPhoto`. I think there are too many tasks at the same time then I want to send a file, wait the result from the webapi and then send next file and so on.

What can I do? What is the best practice for that? Or in any case how can I resolve my problem? :)
Thank you in advance

Comment: is not possible to zip files in one archive and send the archive?

Comment: yes but there are about 3000 pictures. I could create small zips but the number of files could became 1000? I still have the same issues

Comment: I think you can zip all files in 1 archive and send 1 archive

Comment: But in my case there is a 3Gb of zip...

Comment: I don't understand why you have 3000 pictures to send all together. Why you not send the picture after it is created? or create a task that every hour, or every 10 pictures, in background, do a "send"

Comment: I don't want to send all images together. I'm sending one image after another. I can send around 400 and after that the app crashed.