# Xamarin forms: how can I close a NSUrlSessionTask?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, task

I'm trying to resolve my previous [post about sending images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960225/best-practice-to-send-a-lot-of-files-images-from-your-device-to-your-server). I found this [code](https://github.com/dannycabrera/SimpleBackgroundUpload) very useful. Now I have an issue with `Task`.

To avoid to fill all space on a device, I should send 25 images at each time and for each image I create a `CreateUploadTask`. For that I check if all tasks are completed with this code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the pending task.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The pending task.</returns>
/// <remarks>For demo purposes we are only starting a single task 
/// so that's why we are returning only one.</remarks>
private async Task<NSUrlSessionTask> GetPendingTask()
{
    NSUrlSessionTask uploadTask = null;

    if (session != null)
    {
        var tasks = await session.GetTasks2Async();

        var taskList = tasks.UploadTasks;
        if (taskList.Count() > 0)
            uploadTask = taskList[0];
    }

    return uploadTask;
}
```

Unless an image is sent and the event `DidCompleteWithError` raises, the `Task` still running. How can I close a task then?

Comment: If you're just after ending the task if nothing happens, you could add in a timeout duration?

Comment: Yes 2 minutes in `TimeoutIntervalForResource` and `TimeoutIntervalForRequest`